# python: changing row index of pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame called `followers_df` as below:

```
 followers_df

             0
0         oasikhia 
0     LEANEnergyUS
0  _johannesngwako
0     jamesbreenre
0   CaitlinFecteau
0  mantequillaFACE
0         apowersb
0       ecoprinter
0        tsdesigns
0      GreenBizDoc
0        JimHarris
0    Jmarti11Julia
0         JAslat63
0            prAna
0    GrantLundberg 
0        Jitasa_Is
0     ChoosePAWind
0  cleanpowerperks
0          WoWEorg
0      Laura_Chuck
```

I want to change this data frame into something like this:

```
 followers_df

             0
0          oasikhia 
1      LEANEnergyUS
2   _johannesngwako
3      jamesbreenre
4    CaitlinFecteau
5   mantequillaFACE
6          apowersb
7        ecoprinter
8         tsdesigns
9       GreenBizDoc
10        JimHarris
11    Jmarti11Julia
12         JAslat63
13            prAna
14    GrantLundberg 
15        Jitasa_Is
16     ChoosePAWind
17  cleanpowerperks
18          WoWEorg
19      Laura_Chuck
```

how can I do this? I tried:

```
     index = pandas.Index(range(20))
     followers_df = pandas.DataFrame(followers_df, index=index)
```

but it's giving me the following error:

```
  ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 39), indices imply (1, 20)
```

thanks,

Comment: Specifically, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54297213/4909087) on how to set the index from a column or arbitrary iterable.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

you can do

```
followers_df.index = range(20)
```

Answer (score 24):

```
followers_df.reset_index()
followers_df.reindex(index=range(0,20))
```

Comment: I see that your answer is more appreciated, is there something wrong with assigning the index like in my answer?

Comment: Hello, for some reason I am keep getting the same error `Shape of passed values is (1, 39), indices imply (1, 20)` after trying your code....for your reference, I used `pandas.concat()` to formulate followers_df. how can I solve this issue?

Comment: you have duplicates (the number 0), you can't reindex with duplicates, reset_index first

Answer (score 22):

When you are not sure of the number of rows, then you can do it this way:

```
followers_df.index = range(len(followers_df))
```

Comment: @reportgunner Please do not make "Oh My God This Makes My Eyes Bleed" your explanation.

Comment: I think it must be "followers_df.index = range(0, len(followers_df))"? Anyway, in my case it has to be.

Comment: @Ben - Both Works

Comment: not in my case, that's why I figured that out :p